# How to retain a selected value while going through the router in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, angular2-routing

I am very new to angular (currently I believe I am using angular 2) and I'm trying to build an app which will enable a user to select and customise a bundle of products. In order to do this I have imported a JSON file of the product details into the app as follows.

```
{
    "data": {
        "adverts": [],
        "bundles": [{
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Bronze Bundle",
            "price": {
                "installation": "99.99",
                "recurring": "23.99"
            },
            "products": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "9", "10", "15", "15"]
        }, {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Silver Bundle",
            "price": {
                "installation": "99.99",
                "recurring": "23.99"
            },
            "products": ["1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "9", "10", "15", "15"]
        }, {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Gold Bundle",
            "price": {
                "installation": "99.99",
                "recurring": "25.99"
            },
            "products": ["1", "2", "4", "5", "9", "10", "15", "15"]
        }, {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "Build Your Own Bundle",
            "price": {
                "installation": "49.99",
                "recurring": "9.99"
            },
            "products": ["1", "10"]
        }],
        "products": [{
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Product 1",
            "price": {
                "upfront": null,
                "installation": "0.00",
                "recurring": "0.00"
            }
        },  {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Product 3",
            "price": {
                "upfront": "132.00",
                "installation": "9.60",
                "recurring": "2.75"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "Product 4",
            "price": {
                "upfront": "60.00",
                "installation": "9.60",
                "recurring": "1.25"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Product 2",
            "price": {
                "upfront": "60.00",
                "installation": "9.60",
                "recurring": "1.25"
            }
        },{
            "id": "5",
            "name": "Product 5",
            "price": {
                "upfront": "228.00",
                "installation": "9.60",
                "recurring": "4.75"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "6",
            "name": "Product 6",
            "price": {
                "upfront": "96.00",
                "installation": "9.60",
                "recurring": "2.00"
            }

        }]
    }
}
```

My next goal was to import the bundle values into an App component (in this case with the class OrderComponent) and create a select method which would enable a user to select a bundle.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Bundle } from './bundle';
import { Peripherals } from './peripherals';
import { OrderInfo } from './order.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-order',
  template: `
      <h1>Select Bundle</h1>
      <ul class="bundles">
        <li *ngFor="let bundledata of Bundle"
        [class.selected]="bundledata === selectedBundle"
          (click)="onSelect(bundledata)" >
          <h2>{{bundledata.id}}: {{bundledata.name}}</h2>
          <p>{{bundledata.description}}</p>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <bundle-detail [bundle]="this.selectedBundle"></bundle-detail>  

  `,

  providers: [OrderInfo]
})

export class OrderComponent {
    constructor(private orderInfo: OrderInfo) { }
    selectedBundle: Bundle;
    Bundle: {};

    getBundles(): void {
       this.Bundle = this.orderInfo.getBundles();
    }

        ngOnInit(): void {
         this.getBundles();
       }  
    onSelect(bundledata: Bundle): void {
        this.selectedBundle = bundledata;
    };
```

My problem now is that when I navigate to another component in the App the value of this.selectedBundle resets to it's default value of null.

What I would like to happen is that the app remembers which bundle has been selected so that I can use this data at a later point. If anyone could point me in the right direction on how to do this I would greatly appreciate it.

My routing method is coded into the App Component st follows

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Bundle } from './bundle';
import { Peripherals } from './peripherals';
import { OrderInfo } from './order.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <nav>
      <a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
      <a routerLink="/order">Order</a>
      <a routerLink="/customise">Customise Bundle</a>
    </nav>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
   title = 'Bundle App';

}
```

and this is referenced in the App Module

```
NgModule({
  imports:      [     
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
          path: '',
          redirectTo: '/dashboard',
          pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
          path: 'dashboard',
          component: DashboardComponent
        },
        {
          path: 'order',
          component: OrderComponent
        },
        {
          path: 'customise',
          component: ProductDetailComponent
        }
      ])
],
```

Comment: How are you navigating, and what is your project structure ie how your parent and child components resides and communicate. Are you using , separate routing path for each component ?

Comment: I'm Navigating through the RouterModule with each component having it's own seperate routing path. I've edited the origional question with some additional code to show this.

Generally the JSON  file information is called through a service which is then imported into each component which requires it. Hope this helps

Comment: Ok, are you navigating through some click event or just entering the path in url?

Comment: Clicking on one of the three anchor tags in AppComponent

Comment: Each time you are clicking on the button it is leading to a separate component, so whatever data you want to send to  child component send with the click event.

Comment: Got it. Thanks I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you navigate from one route to another, a component is destroyed and a new component is initiated. Note that this is not the case if the newly routed component is a child of the first component but let us not dig deep into this hole.

The solution to this issue is to have a singleton service that holds the state of of the "selectedBundle". "selectedBundle" in your component now is a function that gets its data form the service. In your component typescript and html replace selectedBundle by the selectedBundle() function resolution

```
export class OrderComponent {
constructor(private orderInfo: OrderInfo
            private bundleService: BundleService
) { }
Bundle: {};

getBundles(): void {
   this.Bundle = this.orderInfo.getBundles();
}

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.getBundles();
}  
onSelect(bundledata: Bundle): void {
    this.bundleService.setSelected(bundledata)
};
selectedBundle(){
    return this.bundleService.getSelected()
}
```

Here is the new service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()

export class BundleService {
     selectedBundle: Bundle
     setSelected(bundledata: Bundle) {
        this.selectedBundle = bundledata;
     }


    getSelected() {
        return this.selectedBundle
     }



}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's great!