# How to get previous value of md-select in Angular

Tags: angular, md-select

I have this `md-select`

```html
<md-select
      class="pull-right"
      [options]="nodeNames"
      (handleChange)="onChange($event)"
      optionLabel="name"
      overlayClass="common-md-select-drop-down"
      scrollHeight="350px"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedServer"
    >
</md-select>
```

And in my `.ts` file, my `onChange` function looks like this:

```js
public onChange(event): void {
    this.selectedServer = event.value.name;
    this.getJobStatusData(this.selectedServer);
}
```

So, what I want is when I have selected an item from the dropdown and I navigate to some other component and come back to this component, I want the dropdown to have the previously selected value. So, in my case, `selectedServer` contains the selected value. How do I do that?

**EDIT 1**

```
<md-select
      class="pull-right"
      [options]="nodeNames"
      (handleChange)="onChange($event)"
      optionLabel="name"
      overlayClass="common-md-select-drop-down"
      scrollHeight="350px"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedServer"
      (ngModelChange)="onModelChange(selectedServer, $event); selectedServer = $event;"
    >
    </md-select>
```

Comment: You can create a service that can hold the state of selectedServer. Something like this maybe
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162939/how-to-retain-a-selected-value-while-going-through-the-router-in-angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution would be to use `localStorage` for this purpose:

Store the value in localStorage and when navigate to same component, just read that value and set:

```
   public onChange(event): void {
    localStorage.setItem('selectedServer' : event.value.name);
    this.selectedServer = event.value.name;
    this.getJobStatusData(this.selectedServer);
   }
```

Now in the `ngOninit` of the component:

```
this.selectedServer = localStorage.getItem('selectedServer') || '';
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But its still not working, I have added the updated code in an edit above. Can you please have a look.

Comment: @pranami: Check the updated answer, don't use ngModelChange.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It working now as expected :)

Comment: Happy to help, At first, I misunderstood your question :)